# Sql query to find the Most starting characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simplified scenario, I have a table with the following fields/values:

```
ID  value
1   '12345'
2   '1234'
3   '123'
4   '12'
5   '1'
```

I want to find the record that is the closest to A='1230' and it should correspond to ID=3.

The only implementation I have in mind now is basic... Use a loop to iterate through A substring and do the comparison.
Is there a better way to solve this?

Will appreciate your help

Comment: Why cant it correspond to id = 2?

Comment: Please define "is closest to".

Comment: Id =2 works for values ='1234%' but not '12345%... just a requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @q varchar(5)
select @q = '1230'

select top 1 number, substring(source.value, 1, number)
from master.dbo.spt_values, source
where type='p'
and number<=len(source.value)
and substring(source.value, 1, number) = substring(@q, 1, number)
order by number desc
```

Or using like...

```
select top 1 * from @source s
where @q like value +'%'
order by len(value) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
Declare @valueToSearch int
Set @valueToSearch =1230

;WITH cte
AS
(
  SELECT ID,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ABS(value-@valueToSearch)) AS num FROM Sample
)
SELECT   ID FROM cte
WHERE num=(SELECT MIN(num) FROM cte
```

This will give 2 as the result

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e978e/2)

Comment: Except a) it only works with numbers, and b) the answer he wants is 3.

Comment: I doubt a): It will even work with strings if i declare the variable as varchar and convert it back to int in over clause .b) I just read the question as closest to so wrote the above query .My mistake i will update my answer

Comment: you can't do an ABS on 'ABC' ! :)

Comment: I think he is just referring to numbers rit ?? Anyways your solution was good ..!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @praveen, podiluska's solution worked